# Exercise choices when having crunchy knees

Tags: training, bodyweight-exercises, knees

I want to do some light workout at home but I am concerned about my crunchy knee. One side of me says "stop using that knee!" and the other says "that knee needs some love with mobility drills to oil up"

For example, monkey crawls seems such inoffensive and fun exercise that might keep my knees well lubricated. I totally love doing those, but it is also where I notice that my knees crunch the most.

Is there any general guideline on how to think about exercises that are a sure trigger of noise? I'm mostly convinced that it is a bad thing doing strength/load with hem, but what about mobility? Will it help or cause harm?

Mostly I got the feeling that crunchy articulations need some mobility drills, but I worry if it might do more harm than good. Specially when the crunching seems like it will never go away.

Comment: are your knees literally making a crunching noise? when you look down do your feet rotate in or out? if you squeeze your butt does your pelvis tilt up? any pain in the ankles? I'm attempting to determine if there's another weak point in the chain that could use some love to help out the knee

Comment: it is a grinding noise. My knuckles and shoulders when stiff do make popping noise, but my knees are like grinding cereals. Very rarely I do feel a slight discomfort on my knees, like when you spend a long time seated, except that in my rare cases, it did happen without being seated for a long time. Never had any type of pain during actual exercise

Comment: I would like to disregard if it is a problem of technique. I am not asking about about a specific exercise, just if it is OK seeking full range of motion during warm ups and light mobility drills